# Do sanity checks before or after calling a function?

Tags: c++, idioms, function-call

What makes more sense in regard to performance, code size and idiomatic C++: Leaving sanity checks to the function or doing them beforehand to avoid even calling the function?

Compare the following code where I have the same sanity check in `reserve` and in `insert`. I could skip the later and directly call the function. Should I?

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <cstddef>

struct vector
{
    void insert(std::initializer_list<int> ilist) {
        if (ilist.size() > capacity_) { // ... sanity check here makes sense?
            reserve(ilist.size());
        }
        // ... or just call it regardless?
        // reserve(ilist.size());
        // ...
    }

    void reserve(size_t new_cap) {
        if (new_cap < capacity_) {
            return ;
        }
        // ...
    }
    size_t capacity_;
};

int main()
{
    vector v{6};

    v.reserve(10);
    v.insert({1,2,4,5});
}
```

I would also like discuss this in more general terms. Maybe there are factors I didn't consider. How would you handle such a case?

Comment: Depends on the use case... For reserve it appears meaningful to me, as you 1. won't do that often 2. you don't expect the user to care about previous capacity. For indexing a vector, you might provide both, as std::vector does (unchecked `operator[]` and `at` function) – you'll do that often and don't want to pay for what you don't need, as index access often occurs in loops where you iterate up to size anyway, so check is done already. Your specific sanity check in `insert` is meaningless – You *want* to be able to increase the list, don't you? Otherwise you wouldn't want to *insert*...

Comment: `if (new_cap < capacity_)`  is not just for sanity. If you are trying to mimic `std::vector` then `reserve(4)` should do nothing.

Comment: From a design perspective, most objects are required to maintain their own consistency (e.g. a vector should always ensure their capacity is sufficient, rather than ASSUMING without justification that code which uses the vector can be trusted to ensure capacity is sufficient).   That said, it depends on WHAT code can access the object - if the vector is only accessible to code that takes care to ensure it doesn't exceed capacity of the vector, it may be okay for the vector to not do any checks.   Because of such hypotheticals, this question is really opinion-based.

Comment: You may want to read up on Contracts, an upcoming C++ feature (which did not make it for C++20): https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-a-detour-to-contracts it is about contracts between caller and callee to ensure 'sanity'

Answer (score 3):

It completely depends on what guarantees you want to provide.

Compare to `std::vector`:

- if you call [`std::vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) and the current capacity is not sufficient the vector will make space for the new elements.
- if you call [`std::vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) with a requested capacity that is less than the current capacity then the function does nothing.

For both, the checks are not merely "sanity checks" but they are required.

If you remove them in your `vector` then your vector will be different:

- `insert` assumes that there is enough capacity (its a precondition, if the caller ignores it they get what they deserve: undefined behavior).
- `reserve(x)` makes sure that the capacity after the call is exactly `x`. If the vectors size was larger than `x` it will be adjusted accordingly.

If thats what you want for your `vector` then the checks can be removed. What you should not do in a release build is to keep checks for preconditions. For example bounds checking in an `operator[]`, when `operator[]` is only specified for valid indices. If the caller ignores the precondition (index must be valid) it is their fault. A user that respects the precondition does not want to pay for bounds checking when the `operator[]` is not explicitly specified to do that. Compare to `std::vector` that has an `at()` method, which does bounds checking.

TL;DR: It depends.

Comment: *'What you should not do a in release build [...]'* – maybe worth to hint to `assert(...)` for?

Answer (score 1):

Sanity check are used to find out if one or more argument(s) befor funtion starts, values inside the function, and the function return value are valid to proceed or not. For example think about boundary checking when accessing an element in a vector. This type of checks are studied as precondition, assert, and postcondition. This type of checks often are for development time and normally are turned off in production.

What you call sanity check in your code actually are part of the program logic and you have to do them. The question is where your checks should be located?
As a guideline you sholud keep closely related logics together. So your aproach seems correct.